# why page is redirected when i drop image on div

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, ajax-upload

I am using `jquery 1.9`. I have problem to implement upload image using drag and drop but when I drop image in div then its going redirect and open image in browser i have implement code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meUTg/2/) please check and tell me whats problem why its being redirected

this is my following code

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
    $('.dropuploader').bind('drop', function(e){
        $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'none', 'border' : '4px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'});
        alert("hello there");
        return false;
    });
    $('.dropuploader').bind('dragenter', function(e){
        $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 'border' : '4px dashed #bb2b2b'});
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have missed `ondragover="return false"` use following div html

```
<div class="dropuploader" ondragover="return false">Upload here</div>>
```

instead of

```
<div class="dropuploader">Upload here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the dragover event to make it work.

For example:

```
$('.dropuploader').on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwa3q/

More information about drag events can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations